# Integrate watson conversation with facebook using node.js

Tags: node.js, facebook, salesforce, watson-assistant

How do I integrate my Watson conversation to facebook but passing through my node.js API? The node already is integrated with Watson (and other services like Salesforce, that's why I need to use it). I'm new to this area and this project, so I'm a little lost here.

I already saw some posts here in SO, they mention orchestration, botkit, SDK. But I didn't find a step-by-step tutorial to guide a beginner like me. And I don't know if these things still works because these posts it's kind old and Watson conversation suffered some modifications.

Comment: Yes, that can be done. Depending on your requirements, there are different options. Please be more specific.

Comment: We have a watson skill and we use node.js to integrate with salfesforce and put in production on our website,  now we want to integrate with the facebook chat of our company page.

Watson itself have a button to integrate with facebook chat on a page, but this dont pass through node, in another words we need to integrate facebook chat with node. This informations help you?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may find a number of examples where [BotKit](https://botkit.ai/) (an open source chatbot) has been used as the middleware between different chatbots/messaging systems like [facebook](https://botkit.ai/docs/v0/readme-facebook.html). There are examples on the Botkit site, and focused channels. Here is the link to the [Watson middleware example.](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/botkit-middleware)
I have used it successfully to integrate Watson to Facebook, as an alternative ( and before ) IBM released the official Facebook Assistant integration.

Comment: It is possible to use this BotKit with node.js?

Comment: Yes, have a look at the BotKit documentation. (links above).